# Accessing Hololens Rotations

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I am currently working on a project that involves mimicking the Hololens rotations with a camera on a gimbal. Right now I am just working on outputting the rotations in angles to the console. Currently I am using this script to get the rotations.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraAngle : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        InvokeRepeating("CameraAngles", 0, 5);
    }

    void CameraAngles()
    {
        float roll = Camera.main.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z, pitch = Camera.main.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, yaw = Camera.main.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;
        Debug.Log(roll.ToString("f") + " " + pitch.ToString("f") + " " + yaw.ToString("f") + " ");
    }
}
```

It prints the initial rotation that I've set to the HololensCamera prefab in Unity, but doesn't update when I move around using the Hololens Emulator. How can I get the updated rotations in degrees?

Comment: You should call InvokeRepeating in Start.

Comment: Where have you applied this script ? to `MainCamera`?